# Dependency injection with Dagger2 on Android

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Currently I'm not a fan of dependency injection but I want to give them a try.

This is what I have:

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import rx.android.app.RxActivity;

public class ActivityMain2 extends RxActivity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }
}
```

Now I want to inject Facebook's CallbackManager. Okay let's start.

I created a lot of new classes... really? I have to write much more code to make my developer life easier? :-(

```java
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

@Module
public class FacebookModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    CallbackManager provideCallbackManager() {

        return CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }
}
```

```java
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import dagger.Component;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {FacebookModule.class})
public interface FacebookComponent {

    CallbackManager provideCallbackManager();
}
```

With this new classes I changed the Activity to this:

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import rx.android.app.RxActivity;

public class ActivityMain2 extends RxActivity {

    @Inject
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeDependencyInjector();
    }

    private void initializeDependencyInjector() {

        DaggerFacebookComponent.builder()
                .facebookModule(new FacebookModule())
                .build();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. `callbackManager` is always null.

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your FacebookComponent like this:

```
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import dagger.Component;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {FacebookModule.class})
public interface FacebookComponent {

public void inject(ActivityMain2 activity);
}
```

then your initializeDependencyInjector method:

```
private void initializeDependencyInjector() {

    DaggerFacebookComponent.builder()
            .facebookModule(new FacebookModule())
            .build().inject(this);
}
```